# Decompose a value as a sum of square numbers

Tags: f#, combinatorics

My daughter had a question on her maths homework which was to write a value as a sum of 4 or fewer square numbers.

For example, x = 73 could be 36 + 36 + 1.

I came up with a really brute force algorithm that shows all combinations but when the values get above 1000 it becomes quite slow.

Is there a clever way of achieving this?
Here is my algo in F#

```
let squares = [ 0.. 100 ] |> Seq.map (fun x -> x * x) |> Seq.toList

let rec calc total attempts squares accu results =
  match (total, attempts, squares) with
  | (0, _, _) -> accu :: results
  | (_, 0, _) -> [] :: results
  | (x, _, _) when x < 0 -> [] :: results
  | (_, _, []) -> [] :: results
  | total, attempts, squares ->
    let filteredSquares = squares |> Seq.filter ((>=) total )
    filteredSquares 
      |> Seq.collect(fun sq -> 
                          calc (total - sq)
                               (attempts - 1)
                               (filteredSquares |> Seq.toList)
                               (sq :: accu)
                               results) |> Seq.toList

let res = 
  calc 8058 4 squares [] [] 
  |> Seq.filter(fun lst -> lst <> [])
  |> Seq.sortBy (fun lst -> lst.Length)
  |> Seq.take 1
  |> Seq.toList
```

Additional comments on better F# code would be appreciated as well.
One thing I was wondering was whether I could make it lazy using sequences.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I've attempted to clarify the problem. If I've misinterpreted it, please correct it.

Comment: I'd probably start with something like `total - ((int) sq_root(total)) ^ 2` - ie, subtract the largest square available.  I'm not sure if this always gets you the fewest number of elements, though.  Your big problem is that at every step, you keep trying `1`, or other numbers too small for the remaining number of 'attempts'.

Comment: Switching from `seq.*` to `array.*` will give a pretty significant perf boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let squares = [ 0.. 100 ] |> Seq.map (fun x -> x * x) |> Seq.toList
```

I don't think limiting the squares this way is a good idea. Instead, if you moved it inside `calc`, you could write it as:

```
let squares =
    Seq.initInfinite id
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x * x)
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x <= total)
    |> Seq.toList
```

---

`calc` is a pretty bad name: it doesn't say anything about what the function calculates.

---

If you limit yourself to returning always only the shortest sum, the signature of the method could be simplified quite a lot: you could get rid of `attempts`, `accu` and `results`. This would also somewhat simplify the implementation.

And even if you don't do that, I think that filtering out empty lists should be done inside `calc`, not outside.

---

If you simplify the signature, you could then apply [memoization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Caching#Memoization) to make the computation much faster. Memoization will help here, because what's slowing down the computation is calculating the result for the same `total` over and over.

The implementation could look like this:

```
let rec calculateSquaresSum =
    let calculateSquaresSum' total =
        if total = 0 then
            []
        else
            let squares =
                Seq.initInfinite (fun x -> x + 1)
                |> Seq.map (fun x -> x * x)
                |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x <= total)
                |> Seq.toList
                |> List.rev

            squares
            |> Seq.map (fun sq -> sq :: (calculateSquaresSum (total - sq)))
            |> Seq.minBy (fun sum -> sum.Length)

    memoize calculateSquaresSum'
```

This will calculate the result for values around 10.000 immediately, but 100.000 takes a few seconds, so there likely is a more efficient way to implement this.

---

Though if you're okay with finding just some decomposition with at most the given length, not necessarily the shortest one, having the `attempts` parameter makes sense and makes the computation much faster when the decomposition is possible. (E.g. `calculateSquaresSum(1000000 - 1, 4)` returns immediately with `[998001; 1849; 100; 49]`, while `calculateSquaresSum(100000 - 1, 3)` takes few seconds to return with a negative answer.)

The code:

```
let rec calculateSquaresSum =
    let calculateSquaresSum' (total, attempts) =
        if total = 0 then
            Some []
        elif attempts = 0 then
            None
        else
            let squares =
                Seq.initInfinite (fun x -> x + 1)
                |> Seq.map (fun x -> x * x)
                |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x <= total)
                |> Seq.toList
                |> List.rev

            squares
            |> Seq.map (fun sq ->
                match calculateSquaresSum (total - sq, attempts - 1) with
                | None -> None
                | Some tail -> Some (sq::tail))
            |> Seq.tryPick id

    memoize calculateSquaresSum'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great and is really quick.  Thanks also for the really detailed explanation.

I also came up with another solution using the sqrt as suggested by @Clockwork-Muse which I have put below.

Comment: Actually I deleted the answer because for a number such as 48 it was taking 5 numbers to calculate it and didn't take into account the maximum number of values to use